# Bayesian posterior density estimation, given data and a prior: Can the denominator be evaluated in two different ways?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, posterior

Assume the simple, well-known scenario:  Data = $(x_j, y_j)_{j=1}^{n}$, and that, as usual, the $n$ data points are drawn iid. The $x$'s may be considered non-random, but the $y$'s are observations from a random $Y$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Posterior:} \quad f_{\Theta|\text{Data}}(\theta | \text{dat}) &=   
                                  f_{\Theta  |  Y_1,\cdots,Y_n} (\theta | y_1,\cdots,y_n;  x_1,\cdots,x_n) \\  
                               &= \frac{f_{Y_1,\cdots,Y_n |  \Theta} (y_1,\cdots,y_n  |  \theta;  x_1,\cdots,x_n) f_{\Theta}(\theta)}{f_{Y_1,\cdots,Y_n} (y_1,\cdots,y_n;   x_1,\cdots,x_n)} \\
                                &= \frac{f_{Y_1,\cdots,Y_n  |  \Theta} (y_1,\cdots,y_n  |  \theta;   x_1,\cdots,x_n)  f_{\Theta}(\theta)}{\int_{\theta} f_{Y_1,\cdots,Y_n  |  \Theta} (y_1,\cdots,y_n  |  \theta;   x_1,\cdots,x_n)  f_{\Theta}(\theta) d\theta} \\
                               &=   \frac{f_{\Theta}(\theta) \prod_{j=1}^{n} f_{Y|\Theta}(y_j | \theta ;  x_j)}{\int_{\theta} f_{\Theta}(\theta) \prod_{j=1}^{n} f_{Y|\Theta}(y_j | \theta ;  x_j) d\theta} 
\end{align*}

The above is perfectly understood by me. But I am confused about one question: Why can't the denominator of the posterior density be expressed as (since data are iid)

$\prod_{j=1}^{n} f_{Y}(y_j; x_j) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} \int_{\theta} f_{Y}(y_j, \theta; x_j) d\theta =  
\prod_{j=1}^{n} \int_{\theta} f_{Y}(y_j| \theta; x_j) f_{\Theta}(\theta) d\theta$, which, being a product of integrals, seems to be different from the integral of a product in the standard formula. What am I missing here? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Re: "since data are iid" - but the integral is wrt $\theta$, not the data $y$.

Comment: John - Sorry I don't understand. Could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: One reason would be that in the second form you have to do $n$ integrals, then multiply the results, whereas in the first form you only have to do one integral.  Hence @JohnMadden 's comment about the integral being wrt $\theta$, not $y$, or so I believe.

Comment: Thanks, jbowman. But my hunch is that the second scheme is incorrect. But I cannot see why. It would be great if you or someone else could point out why the second is incorrect.

Comment: Data are not i.i.d., but only conditionally i.i.d. given the parameter so the second approach is wrong. It would be right if you had a datum-specific parameter `\theta_i`, and those were i.i.d. as well (not conditionally i.i.d.)